# Sending an email to the local domain

Tags: c#, asp.net, smtp

I've got a simple method to send emails from the website:

```
... // local vars
using (var mail = new MailMessage(from, sendTo))
{
    using (var smtp = new SmtpClient())
    {
        mail.CC.Add(cc);
        mail.Bcc.Add(bcc.Replace(";", ","));
        mail.Subject = subject;
        mail.Body = body;
        mail.IsBodyHtml = html == -1;
        mail.Priority = priority;
        mail.BodyEncoding = mail.SubjectEncoding = mail.HeadersEncoding = Encoding.UTF8;                    

        smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.PickupDirectoryFromIis;

        try
        {
            if (mail.Body.IsNotEmpty())
            {               
                smtp.Send(mail);                
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            smtp.DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network;

            try
            {
                if (mail.Body.IsNotEmpty())
                {                   
                    smtp.Send(mail);                    
                }
            }
            catch(Exception e)
            {               
                // I log the error here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works great; however, when the sender is `anything@domainname.com` and the recipient is `bob@domainname.com`, the emails are getting stuck in the `Drop` folder of the `inetpub/mailroot` directory and never sent to the recipient.

The question is - how I can get around this to be able to send emails to people on the same (local) domain?

Comment: How does it know where the mail server is? Are you specifying it in the config files?

Comment: Yes, the settings are located within the `web.config` file

Comment: Have you checked your `web.config` smtp configurations? You need to adjust it based on your mail server's configs. As an example, if you were sending through gmail, you would need to set their specific port (587 I guess) and enabling SSL also.

Comment: @Deivis Queirolo Vieira as I have mentioned in the question the settings are OK as the emails are sent to the clients, but not to the local domain boxes.

Comment: Then it's probably a mail server setting if it is working to external addresses. Check the server settings or ask the Admin.

Comment: @VDWWD I was under impression that this might be the case. Mail server admin doesn't know what could it be, me neither. Do you know what setting could cause those emails to bounce back?

Comment: It could be a DNS issue. You can check that at [mxtoolbox](http://mxtoolbox.com). And I know that you can enable/disable delivery to local domains based on IP (or other properties) in some mail severs. But that's also a server issue. That is the extend of my knowledge of the subject.

Comment: To be clear - I assume nothing is being logged in the catch block?

Comment: Hi! Do you have a Exchange server? If it so you can do something like this:
Add a Assembly microsoft.exchange.webservices.dll microsoft.exchange.webservices.Auth.dll then
using Microsoft.Exchange.WebServices.Data;

Comment: then var exchange = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2010_SP2);
            exchange.Credentials = new WebCredentials("user", "password", "mydomain");   
            exchange.AutodiscoverUrl("user@mydomain");

Comment: if (exchange != null)
            {
                EmailMessage message = new EmailMessage(exchange);
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = bodyHtml;
                message.ToRecipients.Add(to);
                message.CcRecipients.Add(cc);

                message.Send();

Comment: @VDWWD thank you for link to the mxtoolbox, we have found couple warnings within there and will see if after sorting them the emails will come through.

Comment: @Vitaly we are not using Exchange server

Comment: I think you should have to add network certificate.

Comment: @Morpheus: Are you using a localdomain FROM address?

Comment: @CharithJ yes, I am.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think it is almost certainly a mail server configuration issue.

According to the [SmptClient.Send() Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swas0fwc(v=vs.110).aspx) any incorrect configuration on your end (Host, Credentials, Port, SSL, Firewall, Anti-Virus etc) should throw an `InvalidOperationException` or a `SmtpException`.

The fact that you can send external mail using the same code and config - which means that you have connectivity to the mail server also very strongly suggests that the problem lies downstream.

I have worked at companies in the past that had different mail servers for internal and external mail delivery.

It could be worth considering what Credentials are being used for the message. Perhaps you have a rule which only allows members of a group (All Company or something like that) to send mail to internals addresses. You could check this by using your real domain credentials (and removing them after the test)

```
smtp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("your.username", "your.password");
```

Either way if no exception is generated the message should have been received on the mail server, and it is up to that server to determine delivery.

Comment: I am pretty sure I've seen the error `RBL restriction: Blacklisted by Internal Reputation Service` within the SMTP logs folder, but not able to find it right now. We will sort the DNS warnings first as per @VDWWD comment and I'll post the outcome afterwards. And answering your comment - nothing is logged within the catch block.

Comment: You are right - it was a mail server config issue. I don't know what was it exactly as admin came back saying "it should be sorted".

Answer (score 2):

I made a tool for sending email`s with this configurations:

```
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage("senderaddress", "recipientaddress");
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient()
{
    Host = "smtpserver",
    Port = 587,//standard port for the most of the server`s
    DeliveryMethod = SmtpDeliveryMethod.Network,
    EnableSsl = true,
    UseDefaultCredentials = false//I got the address and the password so I don`t need the default-credentials
};
NetworkCredential na = new NetworkCredential("yoursender", "senderpassword");//I let the user input his email-address and password to get auntenthificated 
client.Credentials = na;
mail.Subject = "subject";

mail.Body = "body";
mail.IsBodyHtml = true;//I use to send html formated text

try
{
    client.Send(mail);
}
catch (Exception)//for debugging purposes I used the default exception
{
    MessageBox.Show("Sending failed", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

It worked fine for me, when I wanted to send from one domain to the same host, so I hope it works also fine for you!

Answer (score 2):

Try this, it works 4 me.

```
            MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
            mail.From = new MailAddress("mymail@mail.com"); 

                mail.To.Add("anymail@mail.com"); 

                mail.To.Add(empfaenger.Text);

                mail.Subject = "Betreff Text";

                mail.Body = "body Text";

            SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("smtp", "port");

            client.UseDefaultCredentials = false;

            try
            {
                client.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("mymail@mail.com", "anymail@mail.com");

                client.EnableSsl = true;

                client.Send(mail);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                //If not than......
            }
```